# Speed Up - Multiple MySQL Queries on one Page

Tags: mysql, optimization

So I have a real estate website.  I have a page that runs about 5 queries to build a statistics page.  I am wondering if there is a way to speed this up or optimize or combine the queries so that it runs faster.  Right now its take up to 5 seconds to run the page.

Query:

```
SELECT   COUNT(`listing_num`) as `count`,
         AVG(`price`),
         AVG(`square_feet`),
         AVG(`bedroom_total`),
         AVG(`bathroom_total`),
         MIN(`price`),
         MAX(`price`),
         MIN(`square_feet`),
         MAX(`square_feet`),
         MIN(`bathroom_total`),
         MAX(`bathroom_total`),
         MIN(`bedroom_total`),
         MAX(`bedroom_total`),
         MIN(`psf`),
         MAX(`psf`),
         AVG(`psf`)
FROM     `Res_Active2`
WHERE    `status` != 'S'
```

So i run this query about 6 different times on the page with the WHERE clause changed in each so that I can display stats for sold properties, active properties, under contract properties, etc.

What is the right way and fast way to do this?  Can i use cache, combine the sql, anything? I need to speed this page up.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any indexes? MySQL query cache enabled? I've got pages that execute hundreds of queries and are still generated within a second or two.

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Res_Active2` to your question?

Comment: couldnt you jsut `GROUP BY` status instead of using a where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just setup mysql query cache. It will do only once and reuse result in all other queries.
To enable mysql cache see [mysql cache](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/enable-the-query-cache-in-mysql-to-improve-performance.html)

I am pretty sure for you will be enought just add in your /etc/my.conf

```
query_cache_size=30M
```

If that not help, you can create special table which have hold result of that query and update that result every X minutes by external script.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm, now the page loads in 1-2 seconds max.  Thank you so much.